# Connecting/disconnecting signals via eventFilter

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I have an app with hundreds of custom buttons, each one needs multiple signal connections. The connect calls seem to be pretty slow, so I'm trying to connect/disconnect each button's signals via the main window's `eventFilter` using the enter and leave events.

However, sometimes those events seems to be called multiple times, causing RuntimeErrors (when trying to disconnect an event that is already gone).
Here is a snippet of code that shows a similar (and hopefully related) problem using default PushButtons.
To see the runtime error here, run the code, push one of the buttons, then close the window. That's when I see this:

```
RuntimeError: Fail to disconnect signal clicked().
```

Here is the code. Does anybody know if this is a *PySide* bug?

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys

class TestWindow( QWidget ):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( TestWindow, self ).__init__( parent )    
        self.setLayout( QGridLayout() )

    def addWidget( self, w ):
        self.layout().addWidget( w )

    def testCB( self ):
        print 'button connected'

    def eventFilter( self, obj, event ):
        '''Connect signals on mouse over'''
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            print 'enter',
            obj.clicked.connect( self.testCB )
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            print 'leave'
            obj.clicked.disconnect( self.testCB )
        return False

app = QApplication( sys.argv )
w = TestWindow()
for i in xrange(10):
    btn = QPushButton( 'test %s' % i )
    w.addWidget( btn )
    btn.installEventFilter(w)

w.show()
sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 0):

In few cases, when I tested mouse events, showed better performance while events are attached to item class... so don't subclass. Rather :

```
class Button(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, label):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        self.setText(label)

app = QApplication( sys.argv )
w = TestWindow()
for i in xrange(10):
    btn = Button( 'test %s' % i )
    w.addWidget( btn )
```

...then define mouse event for class.